# Need Alternative of adobe flash data table

Tags: jquery, flash, datatable

I have an old code in which Adobe Flash has been used to show a datagrid list with an (csv,excel,pdf,print) button

Current code:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "mColumns": copyColumn,
                "sButtonText": "Copy to clipboard"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "mColumns": copyColumn,
                "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

But now Adobe Flash has become out of support so this buttons (csv,excel,pdf,print) are not displaying anymore. I have tried simple datatable buttons but they are also not working for me.

Changed Code:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bdestroy": true,
    "button": true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'csv'
    ]
})
```

Still the buttons are not displaying

Could anyone help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at any of the [official examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/). Note that (a) you need to include the relevant JS and CSS libraries shown in the examples; (b) also as a side note, you should really be using `.DataTable` now instead of the older `.dataTable`, `order` instead of `aaSorting` - and so on - see [naming standards](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] for further help.